# R Shiny - combine reactivePoll to get latest data from DB with force trigger on input date range change

Tags: r, shiny

Note: The following is not a 'reproducible' example since it relies on a DB back end, but hopefully has enough to provide workable solution ideas.

I want to refresh my data if the database table changes. I am using a reactivePoll() for this one, happily. However, I want the reactivePoll() to forcibly kick in when input date range (or whatever input) changes and not wait for the poll interval to expire. How can I do both?

Here is the general idea of the code I have, but need to be improved to achieve the above result.

```
getTableData <- function(session, startDate, endDate) {
  tableData <- reactivePoll(
    60000, session,
    checkFunc = function() {
      dbconn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), group = 'mysql')
      query <- dbSendQuery(
        dbconn,
        paste0('SELECT MAX(CREATED_AT) as lastCreated FROM MYDBTABLE;')
      )
      lastFeedback <- dbFetch(query, -1)
      dbClearResult(query)
      dbDisconnect(dbconn)

      lastFeedback$lastCreated
    },
    valueFunc = function() {
      query <- paste0(
        "SELECT * FROM MYDBTABLE ",
        "WHERE MY_DATE BETWEEN '",
        startDate, "' AND '", endDate, "';"
      )
      dbconn <- dbConnect(MySQL(), group = 'mysql')
      query <- dbSendQuery(dbconn, query)

      refreshedData <- dbFetch(query, -1)
      dbClearResult(query)
      dbDisconnect(dbconn)

      refreshedData
    }
  )

  return(tableData())
}

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  output$mydata <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(mydbdata(session, input$mydates[1], input$mydates[2]))
  })  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  dateRangeInput(
    'mydates', 'Select Dates:', start = Sys.Date() - 90, end = Sys.Date()
    ),
  dataTableOutput('mydata')
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I don't know if there's a manual way of firing a `reactivePoll`. Here's an alternative - You can set up a reactive variable using `reactiveValues()` that stores the data and use this variable in `output$mydata`. Now set this variable up such that it can be updated through an observer that observes `input$mydates` and also through your `reactivePoll`. This way the reactive variable is updated whenever poll fires or dates change. Drawback is that the code to read data will be somewhat repeated (maybe creating function to read data will mitigate this) but this should work.

Comment: For anyone who runs into this in the future: You can fake a DB backend for a reprex by creating a connection to ":memory:" and writing sample data to it.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my comment, here's a possible alternative. Note that `output$test` is updated whenever slider is changed or `invalidateLater()` is fired -

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(align = "center",
  sliderInput("s", "slider", 1, 10, 1, step = 1),
  verbatimTextOutput("test")
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  x <- reactiveValues(x = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$s, {
    x$x <- "updated via slider" # simulates date changes
  })

  observe({
    invalidateLater(5000, session) # simulates reactivePoll
    x$x <- "updated via Poll"
  })

  output$test <- renderPrint({
    x$x
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```